# Create flowchart with antennas

Tags: floats

I have asked a question before about the same problem. I wanted to make some modifications to the code but the compiler chrashed. Basically I want to remove block x from the code, I have already removed T from the code.

This is how I want it to look: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nKzc5.jpg

This is how it looked before: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Dn6A.png

The code is below:

```
        \documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\usetikzlibrary{fit,positioning}

    \begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 22mm and 5mm,
block/.style={draw, minimum height=20mm, minimum width=5mm,
              font=\boldmath}]
\node (x1)    [block,draw=none]               {};
\node (ht1)   [block,draw=none,right=of x1]            {\hphantom{$\boldmath(HT)^+$}};
%\node (t1)    [block,right=22mm of ht1]       {$T_{1}$};
\node (y1)    [block,right=22mm of ht1]             {$Y_{1}$};
\node (adc1)  [block,right=of y1]             {ADC};
    \foreach \y in {-0.75, -0.25, 0.25, 0.75}
{
    \draw   ([yshift=\y cm]x1.west)--++(180:1cm);
    \foreach \i [remember=\i as \lasti (initially ht1)] in {x1,ht1,y1,adc1}
        \draw [black, -] ([yshift=\y cm]\lasti.east)--([yshift=\y cm]\i.west);
  \draw ([yshift=1-\y cm] adc1.east)--++(0:2+1.5*\y)   node[antenna] {};
}
\draw[densely dotted] (3.75,2) -- (3.75,-7);
  \node[draw] at (2,2) {CPU};
  \node[draw] at (6,2) {RF-chain};

\node (x2)    [block,draw=none,below=of x1]   {};
\node (ht2)   [block,draw=none,right=of x2]  %right=of x2 {\hphantom{$\boldmath(TH)^+$}};
%\node (t2)    [block,right=22mm of ht2]       {$T_{2}$};
\node (y2)    [block,right=22mm of ht2]             {$Y_{2}$};
\node (adc2)  [block,right=of y2]             {ADC};
    \foreach \y in {-0.25, -0.75, 0.25, 0.75}
{
    \draw   ([yshift=\y cm]x2.west)--++(180:1cm);
    \foreach \i [remember=\i as \lasti (initially ht2)] in {x2,ht2,y2,adc2}
        \draw [black, -] ([yshift=\y cm]\lasti.east)--([yshift=\y cm]\i.west);
  \draw ([yshift=1-\y cm] adc2.east)--++(0:2+1.5*\y)   node[antenna] {};
}

\node[draw,inner sep=0pt, fit= (x1)  (x2), label=center:$\boldmath\hat{x}$] {};
\node[draw,inner sep=0pt, fit=(ht1)  (ht2),label=center:$\boldmath(TH)^+$] {};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: in my answer on similar question you already have all elements what you like to have. To be more clear, what is your changes now (in comparison to it), make a sketch, what you like to add or omit  from in it presented variants (there are three pictures). Other wise, your document is duplicate to your previous.

Comment: I thought it would be obvious to you from this pic: http://imgur.com/t9vKHbI   from that pic you see how many lines that are connected to the boxes and which boxes are removed from the second picture. http://i.stack.imgur.com/vdOSr.png

Comment: The problem is that when i started making changes the compiler never stopped so i could not verify where is was making mistakes, if any.

Answer (score 1):

See, if I understand you correctly:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\usetikzlibrary{chains,fit,positioning}

    \begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 20mm and 5mm,
  start chain = going right,
 block/.style = {draw, minimum height=20mm, minimum width=5mm,
                 font=\boldmath,on chain}]
% upper blocks
\node (ht1)   [block,draw=none]             {\hphantom{$\boldmath(HT)^+$}};
\node (y1)    [block,right=22mm of ht1]     {$Y$};
\node (adc1)  [block]                       {ADC};
% lower blocks
\node (ht2)   [block,draw=none,below=of ht1]    {\hphantom{$\boldmath(HT)^+$}};
\node (y2)    [block,right=22mm of ht2]     {$Y$};
\node (adc2)  [block]                       {ADC};
% common input nodes
\node (in2)   [draw,inner sep=0pt, fit=(ht1)  (ht2),label=center:$\boldmath(HT)^+$] {};
% top blocks
    \node (cpu) [above=5mm of in2]     {CPU};
    \node (rf)  [above=5mm of y1]      {RF-chain};
\draw[densely dotted] ([xshift=11mm] cpu.north -| in2.east) coordinate (in3)
                    -- (in3 |- in2.south);
% lines between blocks
    \foreach \y in {-0.75, -0.25, 0.25, 0.75}
{
% 8 input lines
    \draw   ([yshift=\y cm +1 cm] in2.west)--++(180:1cm);
    \draw   ([yshift=\y cm -1 cm] in2.west)--++(180:1cm);
% 4 lines + antennas
        \foreach \j in {1, 2}
    {
    \draw ([yshift=\y cm] y\j.east)--([yshift=\y cm] adc\j.west);
    \draw ([yshift=\y cm] adc\j.east)--++(0:2-1.5*\y)   node[antenna] {};
    }
}
% 2 lines between other blocks
    \foreach \j in {1, 2}
\draw   ([yshift=+5mm] y\j.west)-- ([yshift=+5mm] in2.east |- y\j.west)
        ([yshift=-5mm] y\j.west)-- ([yshift=-5mm] in2.east |- y\j.west);
\end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

[image]

In erasing some node (from third version of my answer, you also need to erase/change all anchors with its name (in drawing lines, for example).

Comment: Thanks for the help! You understand me right about the boxes but i want to have 4 lines between the  Y and ADC boxes.

Comment: hm, now this remind to request do-it-to-me. Try to analyse code and see, what you need to change, that you will have four lines. But with this can be possible to simply part of lines code. I will look in it latter.

Comment: Sure, I am actually trying to modify it but I cant make it right. I modified the last \foreach loop but the 4 lines should stop at the Y box but they continue across to the (TH)^+ box.                                      \foreach \y  in {-0.25, 0.25, 0.75, -0.75}
        {
            \foreach \i [remember=\i as \lasti (initially ht\j)] in {y\j, adc\j}
    \draw ([yshift= \y cm]\lasti.east)--([yshift=\y cm]\i.west);
    %\draw ([yshift= 0.5 cm -\y cm] adc\j.east)--++(0:1+1.5*\y)   node[antenna] {};
    \draw ([yshift=-0 cm -\y cm] adc\j.east)--++([xshift=1.5cm] 0:1+1.5*\y)   node[antenna] {};

Comment: I managed to solve it myself ;) You have thaught me a lot, i appreciate it. I modified the values inside initially and in.                                                            \foreach \y  in {-0.25, 0.25}
        {
            \foreach \i [remember=\i as \lasti (initially ht\j)] in { y\j}
    \draw ([yshift= \y cm ]\lasti.east)--([yshift=\y cm]\i.west);
    }

Comment: Super. One important intention of SE is learning LTeX/.... by asking and than doing. Meanwhile I made on solution for line driving, where i try to make short code for them and reduce number `\foreach` loops (they become lack of clarity.